# Add edit functionality for a system variable to the admin in Drupal 6

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-6, global-variables, drupal-modules

I have created a custom module that sets a system variable using variable_set(). I would like someone with the proper permissions to be able to edit this variable via the admin. I'm sure there are contributed modules that allow you to edit system variables, but I was looking for a way to include this functionality right in my custom module. I would like to maybe hook into the "Site Information" admin form or maybe the "File System" admin form and include a text field where they could edit this system variable and it would save. What's the best way to go about this?

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Site Information form uses [`system_settings_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_settings_form/6) which means you just need to add your variable as an element to the form (using `hook_form_alter()` or, as in the following, `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`) and the system will handle saving it.

```
function MYMODULE_form_system_site_information_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['my_variable_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', // or whatever element makes sense
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('my_variable_name', '')
  );
}
```

Same thing goes for the [`system_file_system_settings()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_file_system_settings/6) form.

Comment: Awesome. That worked, but it is displaying the new field AFTER the save button instead of before it with the other fields.

Comment: You can control the order with the `#weight` property, e.g. `$form['element']['#weight'] = -10` would move it up. Then you just need to play around a bit until you find the right weight

Comment: OK sorry, so something weird is happening. If I put ANY negative weight ie: -10, -2, -1, -50, the field shows as the first in the list no matter what, however, if I put ANY positive number 1, 2, 55, 100, the field appears at the very end after the save button. ???

Comment: You might need to alter the weight of the other items in the form, they're all set to zero by default which explains what you're seeing quite nicely. If you haven't already got it install the Devel module and use the `dpm()` function to display the form array to the screen (`dpm($form);`). Then you can inspect it and see which elements you need to move around

Comment: Yeah that was it. Actually when I did a dpm() the form elements didn't even have weights applied at all, so I guess they must just have defaults of 0. Anyway I ended up just looping through the current form array and applying weights to everything. Then I could put my element where I wanted it. THANKS!